# RequireJS optimization when using variables in require() calls

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I am using [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) and the [r.js](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/) optimizer to build a production-ready app. I noticed that when passing a variable to a `require()` call, everything works as expected.

```
var someDependencies = ["dependency-1", "dependency-2", "dependency-3"];
require(someDependencies);
```

However, when running the optimizer the dependencies aren't read from the variable, and therefore aren't included in the concatenated app script. As I understand it, this is because `r.js` looks for string literals inside of `require()` calls. It does not process JavaScript, so a variable means nothing to it. This is even stated in the [documentation for r.js](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html).

> The optimizer will only combine modules that are specified in arrays
>   of string literals that are passed to top-level require and define
>   calls, or the require('name') string literal calls in a simplified
>   CommonJS wrapping. So, it will not find modules that are loaded via a
>   variable name.

My question is: Is there any way to overcome this so that I can pass variables into `require()` calls but still include them in the r.js build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify the source before passing it to optimizer programatically. In your build configuration specify:

```
onBuildRead: function (moduleName, path, contents) {
    // modify contents here
    return contents;
}
```

This is called before optimizer starts processing the source. You can then match dependencies and replace. Simple concept:

```
var content = 'var someDependencies = ["dependency-1", "dependency-2", "dependency-3"];\n' +
    'require(someDependencies, function(){\n' +
    '  });';

var varName = /require\((\w+)/.exec(content)[1];
var regex = new RegExp(varName + '\\s*=\\s*(\\[.*\\])');
var dependencies = regex.exec(content)[1];
var modifiedContent = content.replace('require(' + varName, 'require(' + dependencies);

console.log(modifiedContent);
```

See [FIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/tkirda/teX3w/1/) demo.